# Can nerves in the human body be spliced with a form of electric wire?

Tags: neuroscience, splicing

This may be a ridiculous question, and is hypothetical, but I'd like a well-supported answer.

Is it possible to splice copper wire (for example) into the human nervous system? Would the charge carried along the nerves then travel into the wire?

Say for example that I wanted my reflexes to be improved (because I know electrical current travels significantly faster through copper wire than our nerves), and wanted to replace a section of my nerves with copper wire. Would it work?

Comment: No, it wouldn't work.

Comment: Actually 'current' (in biological context impulse) moves faster with nerves (https://hypertextbook.com/facts/2002/DavidParizh.shtml) than copper wire (http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/miccur.html#c1).

Comment: Bryan - I appreciate your answer, but do you have a source to back up your claim?